# Why is dart HTTP post is sending previous session data?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an issue where the data I used in the previous form save is getting saved in the database as the current row. For example in the first iteration when I use "test1" as the first name and the second iteration is saved with test2, the second iteration is saved in the database as test1 instead of test2.
The first iteration in saved with empty data for the "firstname".

I am new to dart/flutter.

```
class InitialRegistrationForm extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_InitialRegistrationFormState createState() =>
    _InitialRegistrationFormState();
}

class _InitialRegistrationFormState extends State<InitialRegistrationForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _user = User();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  String msg = '';

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Builder(
                builder: (context) => Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 5),
                        child: Text(
                          'BASIC DETAILS',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            decorationColor: Colors.black87,
                            decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First name'),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your first name';
                          }
                        },
                        onSaved: (val) => setState(() => _user.firstName = val),
                      ),

                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _irfSubmit(
                              _user.firstName,
                            );
                            final form = _formKey.currentState;
                            print(form.toStringShort());
                            if (form.validate()) {
                              form.save();
                              _user.save();
                            }
                          },
                          child: Text('Save'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          }

          _irfSubmit(String fn) async {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            try {
              final http.Response response = await http.post(
                  "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/public_html/include/participant_form_app.php",
                  body: {
                    "firstname": fn,
                  });
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If by saving in the database, you mean when you make the http call you are having this problem because you're calling `form.save();` after you call `_irfSubmit(_user.firstName,);`. If you switch the order it might work.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I found the issue. Its the  _irfSubmit(_user.firstName, );, this should be inside the form.validate if condition. It is working as expected after moving it inside if (form.validate()).